# database sent to a JSON file

Tags: php, database, mysql, json

I'm looking into creating an admin (content management) system with wordpress. However I need the database data to be sent to my application in a specific JSON file. Is there a way of accessing the database mysql in wordpress via php (for example) to send the JSON to my application?

Many thanks for your help in advance,
Max